# Need advice on how to implement this view in Android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to implement a screen like this:

[image]

The view could be scrolled horizontally and inside each of them they could be scrolled vertically. The number of items in each is arbitrary.

Currently I am thinking of implementing it using a recyclerview within a recyclerview but is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Horizontal can be done with ViewPager... Looks like you're trying to recreate the Trello app layout

Comment: Horizontal `ViewPager` is better to use for you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a scrollView and programatically add views in this scrollview. But i recommended recyclerview.

```
int countOfViews = 20;
LinearLayout root= findViewById(R.id.scrollViewRoot);
for(int i = 0; i < countOfViews; i++) {
    View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_test, null);
    root.addView(child);
}
```

XML: item_test.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/scrollViewRoot"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```